# Postgresql query for fetching records

Tags: postgresql

In the below example i want to fetch the no of centers which has different subcenters.
means for center 01 and 04 , subcenter are same. but for centers 05 and 07 , subcenters are different. so please help me writing a query that help me to fetch number of centers that have different subcenters.

```
  ----------------------
  | Center | Subcenter |
  ----------------------
  | 01     |  002      |
  | 01     |  002      |
  | 04     |  001      |
  | 04     |  001      |
  | 04     |  001      |
  | 05     |  001      |
  | 05     |  001      |
  | 05     |  002      |
  | 07     |  003      |
  | 07     |  003      |
  | 07     |  004      |
  | 07     |  005      |
  ----------------------
```

I want the result as below

```
  --------------------
  | count | center   |
  --------------------
  | 2     |  05      |
  | 3     |  07      | 
  --------------------
```

because 05 has 001 and 002 (two different subcenter) ,  and 07 has 003, 004 and 005 (three different subcenter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select center, count(distinct subcenter) as c
from x
group by center
having count(distinct subcenter) > 1
```